# how to log all events that happent in a package to a text file using logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

Hello I have a web application created using JSF and i want to create log file for each method that has been called in specific package using logback

Here is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>D:\testFile.log</file>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.checkaccess" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.compagnie.collabo" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.compagnie.login" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.compteur" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.dispositif" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.fonction" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.horaire" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.jrFerie" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.locaux" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.parametreAbsence" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.parametreAvance" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.parametreConge" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.parametreInterruption" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.configuration.planning" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.jbpm" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.manager" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.share" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.suivirh.absence" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.suivirh.pointage" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.suivirh.conge" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.suivirh.report" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.beans.suivirh.retard" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.converter" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.security" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.security.ldap" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.security.ldap.authenticator" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.security.licence.use" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.servlet" level="DEBUG"/>
    <logger name="ma.nawarit.checker.utils" level="DEBUG"/>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Any help please.

Comment: You need to create an `<appender` for each `<logger` and then use it like you did with the `<root` logger using the fileAppender

Comment: Thank you very much can please give an example if you are free